# Create new Branch from Master branch but not full source code

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am working on a java project and its huge, to compile the full source code in eclipse it will take lot of time, so we will create jar of our compiled source and include it in our project libs and anyone working on particular module he will include only that modules source code so that eclipse need not to compile full source code and execution is faster, recently we moved to git and we have full source in master branch, any developer create the new branch from the master branch he will get the full source code in eclipse and compile is taking more time, but we want to take only particular module or package which am going to work remaining classes will be there in the jar.. How to achieve this in Git.. Help..

Comment: Git actually has no built-in system or commands to directly help you out but fear not. What you have to do is just to do what you just said you want to do. You need to take the source code and build the jar file, then you need to remove the source code from the repository and commit the jar files instead. Before you do this you should separate out the source code of that library to its own repository so that you can still work on it, it's imperative that you figure out how to deal with the source code of this library before going further.

Comment: Suppose when developer wants to work something in login package and if he create the login branch from the master branch he will get the full source code and u r telling to remove all other modules/packages except login because it will be in jar and he wants to works on login module alone, now problem is when he commits and send the merge request, in the commit delete history of all other modules will be there so i can't merge his code to the master branch otherwise in master branch all files will be deleted

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're asking then. You want to clone the repository without getting all the files, but still be able to work on the files? How about just compiling to get the jar files, and add those to a repository somewhere, like artifactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create new branch from `master`, it does has the same source code as `master` since the new created branch point to the same commit after creating.

Assume below is the commit history on `master` branch:

```
...---A---B  master
```

If you create a new branch (such as `newBranch`) from master branch, `newBranch` point to commit `B` when it creates:

```
...---A---B  master,newBranch
```

And if you want to manage part of code on newBranch, just **delete other code and commit the changes**:

```
#remove other code
git add .
git commit -m 'only keep the xxx module on newBranch'
```

And the commit history will be:

```
...---A---B  master
           \
            C  newBranch
```

After developing on newBranch, if you want to apply the xxx module from newBranch to master branch, you can checkout the files to master branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout newBranch -- .
git commit -m 'update files in newBranch to master branch'
```

Comment: Nice explanation with example. It should work. I will try this out. Thank you